# Android Get selected item on click listeners

Tags: android, listview, view, onclicklistener

Goys

I use the following for an on click listener

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()  {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {

            TextView textview1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            TextView textview2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Sr2);
            TextView textview3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Sr3);
            TextView textview4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Sr4);
            TextView textview5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Sr5);
            TextView textview6 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Sr6);
            TextView textview7 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Sr7);
            String text1 = textview1.getText().toString();
            String text2 = textview2.getText().toString();
            String text3 = textview3.getText().toString();
            String text4 = textview4.getText().toString();
            String text5 = textview5.getText().toString();
            String text6 = textview6.getText().toString();
            String text7 = textview7.getText().toString();
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), text7, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }});
```

Works ok but is giving data from wrong item

If I tap on say the 4th item on the listview it give me the data of whatever item is at the top of the listview. If I scroll up the data changes but again only the data of the item is at the top of the listview

I think i need to specify the row but not sure how to get it

Any ideas?

You help as always is appreciated

Mark

Comment: shouldn't you be calling `arg1.findViewById(R.id.Sr2);` , etc ?

Comment: Where is your data is stored inside ArrayList?

Comment: you must have a problem in your adapter, so refer this [link](http://www.pcsalt.com/android/listview-using-baseadapter-android/), i am sure your problem will solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this its just sample

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()  {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {

        TextView textview1 = (TextView)arg1. findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    }});
}
```

**Note:**

You are directly calling `findViewByID()` you need for the particular row get the value from that row. Example,

```
TextView textview1 = (TextView)arg1. findViewById(R.id.textView1);
```

Here `arg1` is your `View`

Comment: Please try to use `public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)` for clarity of what your parameters are actually...

Answer (score 0):

the reason behind calling `onItemClickListener()` is to take an action using one of the returned args e.g. "view" which is returned by the method as arg1, here you just have to refer for arg1 by writing `TextView textview = (TextView)arg1.findViewById(R.id.textView);`
and that would solve your problem.